# PHP Semantic and Dynamic URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I've `programs.php` file that gets all programs from DB and outputs to the screen. And I've another file `programDetail.php` that gets details of every program. I want to display URL like `sitename.com/programs/123` instead of `programDetail.php?p_id=123`. How can I manage it? Is it possible using `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You promise that you’re gonna do some proper research now, if we answer the _is it possible_ part with “Yes”?

Comment: I did some research, but no luck. When I go to `sitename.com/programs/123`, it displays the content of `programs.php`. Now if you know, help me or go away.

Comment: If you tried something and it did not work, then you are supposed to show us what you tried. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Check then below code, it works for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Some-text-goes-here/([0-9]+)$ /programDetail.php?p_id=$123
```

Comment: It didn't work for me: **Not Found** The requested URL /some-text-goes-here/123.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using .htaccess. You can do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^programs/([0-9]+)/?$ ./programDetail.php?id=$1
```

Alternatively, you can use a library (I know this isn't what you asked for) called [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/) to handle your routing

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess, like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^programs/(\d+)*$ ./programDetail.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Sir, it displays the content of the `programs.php`.

Comment: my snippet has ./programDetail.php?id=$1 not programs.php?id=$1

Comment: I've tried it. When go to `sitename.com/programs/123`, the browser displays the content of `programs.php`.

Edit: `programs.php` has the title **Programs** and `programDetail.php` has the id of the program (for example, 123).

Comment: bizarre. You sure you edited the correct .htaccess, or that nothing else overrides it, or you accidentally overwritten your programDetail.php with the contents of programs.php?

Comment: Sure, I copied your snippet. I see the content of `programs.php`, not `programDetail.php`'s.